# react-hook-form batch async validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Say I have 3 separate fields in my form and I want to validate them asynchronously, i.e. by sending a request to the server. Currently, I am doing this manually on the submit handler. I know you can define your custom validate() function for registered controllers, but that would cause 3 separate requests to be performed.

How to batch them together so there is only one request for all three fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [`mode`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform#:%7E:text=Props-,mode,-%3A%20onChange%20%7C%20onBlur) in `useForm` to "onSubmit" to make the validation trigger on the submit event.

```js
useForm({
    ...
    mode: "onSubmit"
})
```